# String to HTML?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, html-encode

I can't understand why the code below return the string as a string but not as html,

```
function en_code($string)
{
    # find the match of [br] = a break = <br>
    $output = preg_replace('/\[(?:&nbsp;|\s)*([br]+)(?:&nbsp;|\s)*\]/', '&lt;$1 /&gt;', $string);

    # return the result
    return $output;
}

$string = 'Wallace and Gromit\'s Children Foundation the whole campaign was exemplary, showing true professionalism, creativity and an amazing understanding of what makes a strong news story.\'[br][br]Wallace & Gromit\'s Children\'s Foundation';

echo en_code($string);
```

returns,

```
 Wallace and Gromit's Children Foundation the whole campaign was
 exemplary, showing true professionalism, creativity and an amazing
 understanding of what makes a strong news story.'<br /><br />Wallace &
 Gromit's Children's Foundation
```

but it should return like this,

> Wallace and Gromit's Children Foundation the whole campaign was
>   exemplary, showing true professionalism, creativity and an amazing
>   understanding of what makes a strong news story.'
> Wallace &
>   Gromit's Children's Foundation

What I am trying to do is to convert `[br]` to `<br />` in the function.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want HTML, why are you translating it to `&gt;` and `&lt;`? (See [this test](http://regexr.com?2uu3p) when you don't use `&gt;` & `&lt;`)

Comment: how can I convert `&gt;` and `&lt;` to html?

Comment: Why such a complex regex when you could just do `str_replace('[br]', '<br />', $string)`?

Comment: because the string is input by the user, and you know users don't type 'nicely' in the field...

Answer (score 3):

Try changing

```
$output = preg_replace('/\[(?:&nbsp;|\s)*([br]+)(?:&nbsp;|\s)*\]/', '&lt;$1 /&gt;', $string);
```

to

```
$output = preg_replace('/\[(?:&nbsp;|\s)*([br]+)(?:&nbsp;|\s)*\]/', '<$1 />', $string);
```

The replacement was using the HTML code for `<` and `>` rather than the actual characters.

Comment: thanks. got it. if I want to keep that `&lt;$1 /&gt;` - how can I convert that to html?

Comment: @lauthiamkok: Pass your result through [`html_entity_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

Answer (score 0):

You're using `&lt;` and `&gt;` which are HTML entities use to display the `<` and `>` symbols on html pages. You need to use specifically these chars intead of the entities in order for the result to have valid html tags.